# How to hook up github oauth 2.0 with http in javascript

Tags: javascript, github, oauth-2.0, github-api, github-oauth

Good day,

I am trying on github oauth2.0 apis and got stuck on calling `/access_token` with fetch and axios.

I have successfully gotten `/authorize` api to work and have `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `code` passed successfully to `getAccessToken` function. However, failed at making the fetch with cors error issue returned.

**Things that I had explored**

- https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/javascript/2018-06-24-oauth-with-node-js/
- https://github.com/sohamkamani/node-oauth-example
- https://github.com/evert/fetch-mw-oauth2

**Code:**

```
export const authorize = async () => {
  const uri = withQuery('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize', {
    client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/authorize',
    scope: 'read:user',
  });
  window.location.replace(uri);
};

export const getAccessToken = async (code: string) => {
  const { VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID, VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET } = process.env;

  const uri = withQuery('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', {
    client_id: VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
    code,
  });

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: uri,
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
    },
  }).then(response => {
    console.log('response: ', response);
  });
};
```

**Axios error:**

```
authorize:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=abcdefgh&client_secret=abcdefgh' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

createError.js?2d83:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:81)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of some security-related limitations, Github prevents developers from implementing the OAuth Web Application Flow on a client-side only application.

References:

- https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/330

Working Solution:

- https://github.com/prose/gatekeeper